# How do you restrict permissions to a specific action with guardian and phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have set up guardian to encode specific permissions in the token, however, I would like to restrict this in my `UserController` to just require it on specific actions (`[:index, :show, :edit, :update, :delete]`). I use the following line at the top of the controller to require the `admin: [:cms]` permission for the entire controller:

`plug Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions, handler: Ay.Guardian.ErrorHandler, admin: [:cms]`

This works fine but I would like to add a guard like clause to this (e.g. `when action in [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :delete]`) but I can't seem to get this to work the way I want to.

I realize I can easily check the claims in each action but because of the large amount of controllers I would like a more generic approach.

Comment: what happens when you use ```when action in [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :delete]```?

Comment: see my answer below :) @TimPelgrim

Comment: did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling the plug like this:

```
plug Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions, [handler: Ay.Guardian.ErrorHandler, admin: [:cms]] when action in [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :delete]
```

*(the `[]` are important!)*

To make it a bit more readable try `alias` the plug like:

```
alias Guardian.Plug.EnsurePermissions

plug EnsurePermissions, [handler: Ay.Guardian.ErrorHandler, admin: [:cms]] when action in [:index, :show]
```

Comment: @TimPelgrim did my answer fix the problem?